# $A$ is $J$-measurable, $A$ is null $\implies\text{vol}(A) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem,

> Let C $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a J-measurable set such that C has zero measure. Show that,
> vol(A) = 0.

I only have real analysis tools and I try a contradiction approach, i.e.,

$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 \, ; \, \forall (C_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ open rectangles} \, , \, C   \not\subset \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} C_i \text{ or } \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} vol(C_i) \geq \epsilon. $$

In this ideia I state:

If $V(C) \neq 0$, by definition of volume, given the rectangle $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $C \subset A$, we have,

$$ \int_A \chi_C \neq 0, $$

where $\chi_C$ denotes the indicator function of the set C in the rectangle A, i.e.,

$$ \chi_C: A \to \{0,1\} \, ; \, \chi_C(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \, x \in C; \\ 0, \, x \in A - C. \end{cases}$$

As $\chi_C \geq 0$, it follows
$$\int_A \chi_C = \int_A^- \chi_C > 0,$$

where the second integral denotes the superior Riemann integral. So,

$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 ; \int_A^- \chi_C \geq \epsilon.$$

Follows, from the definition of this kind of integral,

$$ \inf \{ U(\chi_C ; P) | P \in \mathcal{P}(A)\} \geq \epsilon,$$

where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes the set of the partitions of the rectangle A. Particularly, given an arbitrary $P_0 \in \mathcal{P}(A)$,

$$U(\chi_C ; P_0) \geq \epsilon $$
$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{B \in P_0} M(\chi_C; B) \cdot vol(B) \geq \epsilon$$
$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{B' \in P_0} vol(B') \geq \epsilon,$$

where B' denotes the rectangles from the partition $P_0$ such that the intersection with C is not empty. Because $M(\chi_C; B') = 1$ and for the others B's $M(\chi_C; B) = 0$.

Now I'm with difficulties to conclude the proof. I'm not certain if given a sequence of open rectangles such that C is in the arbitrary union of the elements of this sequence always is possible to extract a partition of A formed by elements of this sequence. If yes, I can use the last identity to control the sum of the volume of the elements and get in a contradiction showing that C has no zero measure.

Any hints in how to proceed?

Is that approach the most simple and easy way to attack that problem?